# Why is my time picker not showing seconds using react bootstrap?

Tags: reactjs, forms, react-bootstrap, timepicker

I am using react-bootstrap (v2.4) for a form in which I want the user to specify hours, minutes and seconds (hh:mm:ss). See the code I am using below:

```
<Form>
  <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="timeSelector">
    <Form.Label>Test</Form.Label>
    <Form.Control type="time" step="1" />
  </Form.Group>
</Form>
```

This works as expected in Chrome on Mac, but on both iPhone and iPad it only shows hh:mm in Chrome. Also on Safari, on hh:mm is shown. I am already using step="1", but this doesn't make any difference.

Any idea how to fix this or what alternative approach I can use?